# I am an SME/SuperUser who has been asked to comment on our QA procedures. What types of UAT functionality is normally tested by an SME/SuperUser?

Tags: quality-assessment

I work for a company that provides BI solutions. I am an SME/Super User and one of my typical duties is to evaluate system configuration for new installs and upgrades prior to the client receiving it.

We are in the process of re-evaluating our roles and responsibilities and my group is under the belief that many of our duties in this regard should be handled by our (very small) testing group.

Examples of things we currently examine that we think should be tested prior to reaching us:

1. Are new documents able to be created?
2. How long does it take for a new document to be created?
3. Are all KPIs present in the document?
4. Are the values of the KPIs reasonable?
5. Does basic functionality work (e.g., sorting, filtering)?

There are about 15 of these types of tasks for about 30 individual documents.

In addition, we also examine the installs to ensure that any customizations that were requested are present/functioning based on our industry experience. E.g., For our CRM tool: Does the system reflect the client's sales team's commission structure?

We would like to limit our review to the latter type of tasks but wanted to ask experts to better understand what is typical.

Appreciate your comments.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what you have listed, in my personal opinions, you could also test:

- Are you able to modify / delete existing documents?
- Accessing privileges, surely not everyone is allowed to do everything for a given document
- Perform simple boundary tests against key values, e.g. input invalid numbers and see what happens.
- Save / retrieve changes.

Answer (score 1):

On high level, a developer should build the system as per the requirements and get it unit tested before handing over to QA.

A tester should perform integration & system testing  to validate the system if ready for final user acceptance testing.

A business analyst should pick up from there to test the system with real user end to end scenarios only to accept(or reject) the system from end user perspective.(UAT)

On every point , each team can reject outright if system under test doesn't pass the entry criteria set for that stage which already is in place  accepted by all stakeholders ,as part of test plan.